# Cannot read property 'has' on click but it can on page ready

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that adds a click event to items, that looks like this, when I click on the item, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined

`DomElement` is basically a wrapper for `HTMLElement` as you can see below.

```
class MyClass {
    private static _elements: DomElement[] = [];
    private static createClickHandlers() {
        MyClass._elements.forEach(element => {
            element.components.forEach(component => {
                if (typeof component['click'] == 'function') {
                    element.element.addEventListener('click', component['click']);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my wrapper class for my `HTMLElement`, it has components on it which are just classes that extend the class `Component`.

```
class DomElement {
    private _element: HTMLElement = null;
    private _components: Component[] = [];
}
```

This is where all the functionality takes place, as you can see it contains a click function.

```
class AnotherComponent extends Component {
    click(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Throws an error:
        console.log(this.class.has('monkey'));
    }
    start() {
        // Works:
        console.log(this.class.has('monkey'));
    }
}
```

Whenever a component gets created, the `init` function is ran which looks like this:

```
class Component {
    public class = null;

    public init(element) {
        this.class = new Class();
        this.class.element = element;
    }

}
```

So now everything gets setup properly, but when I click on the element the class item is undefined. I tried binding the component to the element, but that didn't do anything helpful.

I also have a `start` that can be placed in the class, and when that runs it doesn't throw an error it runs the `has` function no problem. This executes on `DOMContentLoaded`.

So, what is causing the element to not be there when an item is clicked, but it is there when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the click handler without binding it, so when it is invoked the `this` in the body of the function isn't the instance of `Component`.
It should be:

```
class MyClass {
    private static _elements: DomElement[] = [];
    private static createClickHandlers() {
        this._elements.forEach(element => {
            element.components.forEach(component => {
                if (typeof component['click'] === 'function') {
                    element.element.addEventListener('click', component['click'].bind(component));
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Note also that I've changed `MyClass._elements` to `this._elements`.

Also, if all subclasses of `Component` need to implement a `click` method then you better add it as abstract:

```
abstract class Component {
    public class = null;

    public init(element) {
        this.class = new Class();
        this.class.element = element;
    }

    abstract click(event: MouseEvent): void;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that was the issue! I was binding to element `component['click'].bind(element)` instead of component